# Magento 2 search criteria

Tags: magento2, magento2-api

I need to get `product collection` by product updated date. I am using below API request.

> `[http_api]/magento2/rest/V1/products/
>        ?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at
>        &searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2017-12-1
>        &searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq
>        &searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][field]=updated_at
>        &searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][value]=2018-03-01
>        &searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=lteq`

but i am `getting all products from admin` in response.

Please suggest me how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to:

```
[http_api]/magento2/rest/V1/products/
   ?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at
   &searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2017-12-1
   &searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq
   &searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=updated_at
   &searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=2018-03-01
   &searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=lteq
```